# How to un-eat memory?

Tags: memory

Consider this code:

```
MemoryInUse[]
T = Table[RandomComplex[], {i, 1, 6000}, {j, 1, 6000}];
MemoryInUse[]
T += T\[ConjugateTranspose];
MemoryInUse[]
{Es, Ys} = Eigensystem[T];
MemoryInUse[]
T = Table[RandomComplex[], {i, 1, 6000}, {j, 1, 6000}];
MemoryInUse[]
T += T\[ConjugateTranspose];
MemoryInUse[]
{Es, Ys} = Eigensystem[T];
MemoryInUse[]
$HistoryLength = 0;
MemoryInUse[]
Clear[T]
MemoryInUse[]
Clear[Es, Ys]
MemoryInUse[]
ClearSystemCache[]
MemoryInUse[]
```

It gives me the following results:

> 15808208
>
> 880820520
>
> 1456822832
>
> 4919500424
>
> 5783503032
>
> 6359505096
>
> 9822181440
>
> 9822182648
>
> 9822182112
>
> 9822181384
>
> 9822162952

Clearly, the memory clears negligibly on any of `ClearSystemCache`, `Clear` and zeroing `$HistoryLength`. Repeating its execution leads to swapping, after start of which I hurry up to kill MathKernel before my X or WM or anything else are OOM-killed.

So what are the working ways to release the memory?

Comment: You need to put `$HistoryLength = 0` before your calculations.

Comment: @ybeltukov but shouldn't zeroing it clear all the history already present?

Comment: It is just a global variable. It not clear the history. You can still access to the history by `ByteCount@Out[12]` or `ByteCount@%10`. It can be cleared by `Unprotect[In, Out]; Clear[In, Out];` but it is not a good idea.

Comment: @ybeltukov Wow, you're right. This could make an answer.

Comment: Done! P.S. `RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {6000, 6000}]` is faster.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$HistoryLength` is just a global variable. It not clear the history. You can still access the history by

```
ByteCount@Out[12]
ByteCount@%10
```

It can be cleared by

```
Unprotect[In, Out]
Clear[In, Out]
```

However, it would be better if you set `$HistoryLength=0` before your resource-intensive code.

P.S. It would be great to have `$HistoryMemoryLimit` or something like this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method I've prepared for clearing memory between function iterations.  It's a working model although I haven't needed to use it yet.  It fully quits memory between each iteration.  Each section needs to be in a separate cell to work.  The second cell runs a four-cell loop for as many iterations as specified.  The `functionToEvaluate[n]` should be user-specified, and would be limited to not doing things that would break the loop.

Note, this code modifies a `$FrontEnd` option which persists across sessions, so if you experiment with it you may want to check the default value `True` is set when you're done.  The last section does that.

```
(* Setup section *)
numberOfIterations = 4;
initialOptionState = Options[$FrontEnd,
"ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"][[1, -1]];
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,"ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" -> False]
(* initialise temporary log file *)
Put[{initialOptionState, numberOfIterations, MaxMemoryUsed[]}, 
 FileNameJoin@Append[FileNameSplit@$TemporaryDirectory, "log.m"]]
(* The log keeps a record of the initial option status, 
numberOfIterations and memory use. *)
ReadList[FileNameJoin@Append[FileNameSplit@$TemporaryDirectory, "log.m"]]
```

[image]

```
(* Evaluate only this cell to launch the iteration procedure *)
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
Do[FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "SelectNextLine"]], {2}];
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
```

[image]

```
Quit[];
```

[image]

```
iteration = Length[log = ReadList[
     FileNameJoin@Append[FileNameSplit@$TemporaryDirectory, "log.m"]]];
numberOfIterations = log[[1, 2]];
PutAppend[{DateList[], MemoryInUse[], MaxMemoryUsed[]}, 
 FileNameJoin@Append[FileNameSplit@$TemporaryDirectory, "log.m"]];
(* Define or Get the function to be iterated *)
functionToEvaluate[n_] :=(*Print[n]*)n^2
functionToEvaluate[iteration];
```

[image]

```
If[iteration < numberOfIterations,
 nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
 SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell, 4];
 SelectionEvaluate[nb],
 initialOptionState = log[[1, 1]];
 SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
  "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" -> initialOptionState];
 Print[iteration, " interations completed."]]
```

[image]

```
Print["This cell does not get evaluated by the loop."]
```

[image]

```
(* Viewing the log *)
Grid[ReadList[FileNameJoin@
   Append[FileNameSplit@$TemporaryDirectory, "log.m"]]]
```

[image]

```
(* Check option has been reset to former value *)
Options[$FrontEnd, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"]
```

[image]

```
(* Use this to reset option, if required (for instance if loop is interrupted). *)
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" -> True]
```

I have noticed the option's state sometimes get set counter to my expectations, most probably due to the quitting and resetting, so sometimes the loop only runs once.  I haven't completely finished figuring that out yet, but if you have suggestions I'd be interested to hear.  In practice, once it's looping it can be left to run.  Code improvement suggestions welcome.

Another approach to running fresh kernels would be to use one kernel to run another repeatedly, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7866055/879601).