# How to deallocate memory of mathematica.exe

Tags: memory

First

```
r[t_] = {10 Cos[3/2 π t], 10 Sin[3/2 π t] + 3 Cos[6 t], 3 (1 - Cos[5/2 π t]) + 1};
```

Next, when I evaluate these lines, the memory reserved by mathematica.exe increases by 110 mb.

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm[None], Tube[FirstCase[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 1}],
  Line[___], 0, {0, ∞}], 1/8]}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-15, 15}, {0, 15}},
    Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {-20, -15, 0}]
```

Everytime something is changed in the plot I reevaluate the code, and then the previous plot is gone. However, the memory isn't freed, and eventually there is no more memory. `Exit` doesn't work because the memory is reserved by mathematica.exe. I also tried `$HistoryLength = 0` which doesn't make a noteworthy difference.

How to free this memory without terminating mathematica.exe?

Edit: When leaving out `CapForm[None]` then `MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd]` is as good as constant. So this is a probably just a bug of `CapForm`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to un-eat memory?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38842/how-to-un-eat-memory)

Comment: @m_goldberg I can't find an answer in there, everything seems to be about the kernel