# How to remove all of the memory used by Mathematica

Tags: memory

#### Backgroud

When I create the notebook,it will be made mess by me sometimes.If I use `Remove` to remove those variables,the memory cannot release still.So I have to close this mess notebook and restart the `MMA` to create another new notebook.I want to find way by programal method to avoid restarting the `MMA`,which can remove all of the variable and can release the memory.

---

Test code:

```
In[1]:= memory := Row[{"Memory Used:", MemoryInUse[]/1024^2., " MB"}];
memory
Out[2]= Memory Used:99.3511 MB

In[3]:= a = RandomReal[1, 20000000];
memory
Out[4]= Memory Used:255.345 MB
```

As we see,the value of memory used by *Mathematica* currently is $255.345MB$.How to release it and make it back to $99.3511M$?As I try,the `ClearAll`,`Remove` and `ClearSystemCache` cannot do this.

---

**Update:**
As this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38863/21532),I change the test code to be following:

```
In[1]:= c`memory :=Row[{"Memory Used:", MemoryInUse[]/1024^2., " MB"}];
c`memory
Out[2]= Memory Used:58.117 MB

In[3]:= a = RandomReal[1, 20000000];
c`memory
Out[4]= Memory Used:216.487 MB

In[5]:= Unprotect[In, Out];
Clear[In, Out]
Quiet[Remove["`*"]]
$Line = 0;

In[1]:= c`memory
Out[1]= Memory Used:63.2716 MB
```

The last output is $63-58=5M$ lager than first output still.How to release it?

Comment: Did you try `$HistoryLength = 0;` ?

Comment: @Sumit It relate to this topic?

Comment: the large chunk of memory might be a history. By telling MMA not to store any history you might be able to free the memory (works for me sometimes). You can also try ``Clear["Global`*"]`` or simply `a=.` .

Comment: from what youve written I wonder if you know you can simply restart the kernel? Im not sure these more complicated approaches are worth the effort to save 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Szabolcs wrote in [this great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/861/731), there are, from the old days, two functions that are meant to restore the kernel to its former state and recover as much memory as possible without having to restart it.

Try this on a fresh kernel:

```
memory := Row[{"Memory Used:", MemoryInUse[]/1024^2., " MB"}];
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]
memory
a = RandomReal[1, 20000000];
memory
CleanSlate[];
ClearInOut[];
memory
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All memory was recovered. Note that it only resets definitions that were made after the package was loaded, therefore in this case it didn't reset the definition for `memory`.

Comment: I cannot understand what meaning of `slate`,and I found a strange thing,when I use the `ClearInOut`,It will result to more memory to be used.This is a [reproduce phenomenon](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-11-13-20-14-10.png).

Comment: @yode It recovers as much memory as possible but not all of it in some cases. Szalbocs notes in his original answer that memory cannot be recovered perfectly, this is the best that we have. As for the meaning of "slate" it could be thought of as coming from the common translation of "tabula rasa" to either "clean slate" or "blank slate," but originally, as the article says, it came from the use of slate sheets.

Comment: I's seem ``Internal`Restart`` can do it more competely.

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear [`InString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InString.html) and [`MessageList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageList.html) as well since these take up memory.

```
Quit[]

c`mem := UnitConvert[Quantity[MemoryInUse[], "Bytes"], "Megabytes"] //N

c`mem
```

> ```
> 69.6199 MB
> ```

```
a = RandomReal[1, 20000000];

c`mem
```

> ```
> 228.553 MB
> ```

```
Unprotect[In, Out, InString, MessageList];
Clear[In, Out, InString, MessageList];
Remove["`*"];
Protect[In, Out, InString, MessageList];
$Line = 0;

c`mem
```

> ```
> 68.5551 MB
> ```

I got this information while at WTC2014 from a talk titled [Beyond Quit[]: Master Your Memory in the Wolfram Language](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9030/); more info in there. There is a utility in the notebook called `` Utilities`CleanSlate`ClearInOut[] `` that  does not seem to work when called but putting the commands directly in your notebook seems to do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a result with and without `$HistoryLength = 0;` with MMA10.1 Linux.

[image]

As you can see `$HistoryLength = 0;` does save some extra memory.

Comment: But I want to save that result such as `%3` or `%4` **before I release the memory***.