# How to release the space took up by specify variable

Tags: memory

Actually relate my [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131002/how-to-remove-all-of-the-memory-used-by-mathematica).But I don't want to clear all memory took up by *Mathematica*.

```
memory:=Row[{"Memory Used:",MemoryInUse[]/1024^2.," MB"}]
memory
(* Memory Used:109.582 MB *)

a=RandomInteger[1,{10^8}];
memory
(* Memory Used:871.666 MB *)

b=RandomInteger[1,{10^8}];
memory
(* Memory Used:1634.61 MB *)
```

I want to clear the variable `a` and release the space took up by variable `a` but keep the `b`. Is possible?

Comment: Have you tried `$HistoryLength=0` and `Clear[a]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes,I have.But it don't work..

Comment: We really need a canonical question for this sort of problem. It's not clear, it's not easy to find in the documentation, it has finer points such as the requirement to delete the `Out` cells and make sure they're not anywhere in the `DownValues` for `Out` either. I say, this should stay open.

Comment: See [common pitfalls / $HistoryLength](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80978/4999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$HistoryLength = 0` and `Clear[a]` works for me:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
memory:=Row[{"Memory Used:",MemoryInUse[]/1024^2.," MB"}]
memory

a=RandomInteger[1,{10^8}];
memory

b=RandomInteger[1,{10^8}];
memory

Clear[a];
memory
```

> Memory Used:227.932 MB
>
> Memory Used:990.87 MB
>
> Memory Used:1753.81 MB
>
> Memory Used:990.868 MB

Comment: Oh,I have misunderstand it before.Thanks a lot..

Comment: `a = RandomInteger[1, {10^8}]; (* <-- this is In[136] *)
Clear[a];
Unprotect[Out]; Out[136] =.; Protect[Out];` is also a working approach.